# Detecting empty TIFFs

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, c++, linux, vrt

How to detect if a TIFF or VRT is empty. I don't want to loop all over values.
By empty, I mean full of NODATA values.

A C++ method is preferred.

Using the flag `-stats` with `gdalinfo` I can get STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT which is more than enough.

Comment: Because TIFF does not have an "all pixels are nodata" metadata you must check every pixel. You can for example compute a histogram and if min=max=nodata you have found it. Of course it helps if the image happens to have statistics already.

Comment: @user30184 if you want to know if all are NODATA you can stop if you find any actual data - there's no point carrying on after that!

Comment: As a comparison when you write your own code, gdalinfo computes statistics for a 12000x12000 sized RGB image in less that 10 seconds.

Comment: thank you @user30184  for your input, I updated the question above, can you take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so using the flag `-stats` with `gdalinfo` I can get `STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT` which is more than enough.