# How to detect whether a sparse RGBi GeoTIFF is empty using GDAL CLI?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalinfo

The solution from [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/440938/1886) doesn't seem to work with a sparse RGBi GeoTIFF - the last channel is considered valid even though it's empty:

```
❯ gdalinfo -json empty.tiff | \
  jq --raw-output '.bands[].metadata."".STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT'
0
0
0
100
```

Comment: Is the last channel marked as alpha in your image? Maybe you should correct the color interpretation.

Comment: It is. I'm not familiar with GeoTIFFs; I might have to ask my colleagues about this.

Comment: I would first make a new test after editing the 4th band to mean "undefined" https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html#cmdoption-colorinterp_-X instead of alpha.

Comment: I don't control the source TIFFs.

Comment: Make a copy then. If you use the GDAL VRT format https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html it is cheap.

Comment: Making a copy of 100s of TBs is out of the  question, I'm afraid.

Comment: If you read what GDAL VRT format is, it is a very small XML file that is referencing the original image data. With VRT you can turn the alpha band logically into a 4th data band. Try it: `gdal_translate -of VRT image.tiff image.vrt`. Once you have the VRT you need to do some editing with tools that you like best. Text editor like sed is one alternative.

Comment: Thanks! All that said, I don't think this is getting closer to an answer - I can't know (programmatically) whether the 4th data band is meant to be data or empty; I really need to check whether the TIFF is sparse.

Comment: Did you try? The meaning of alpha is to tell if the pixels in the rest of the bands are valid or not and therefore it is well possible that you would get the information that you are after with gdalinfo once you have turned the interpretation of the 4th band from alpha into data.

Comment: "The meaning of alpha is to tell if the pixels in the rest of the bands are valid or not […]" That won't be the case for RGBi TIFFs. But anyway, it simply looks like the GDAL tools can't do this. I'm using `exiftool` to extract the `TileByteCounts` tag instead.

Comment: The meaning of the 4th band is stored into the TIFF metadata. If it is now stored wrongly as alpha into your source data then GDAL believes it. If you correct the TIFF metadata (by using the virtual VRT dataset in the middle) then GDAL probably trusts it and handles the 4th band as a normal data band. But it is up to you if you do not want to try that method. I am pretty sure that GDAL tools can.

Comment: "The meaning of the 4th band is stored into the TIFF metadata." Oh, which field & value should I look for?

Comment: https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/extrasamples.html.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [a `STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT` of 0 doesn't mean that there are literally 0 valid pixels](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/471623/1886). Also, there doesn't seem to be any GDAL CLI tools which print out the tags for an image. So I guess the answer, for now, is simply "you can't".

Working alternatives:

- Use `exiftool -json PATH` to get tags as a list of JSON objects, then check that `TileByteCounts` is 0.
- Use the `tifffile` library and [check that `TiffFile(path).pages.first.tags["TileByteCounts"].value == (0,)`](https://github.com/linz/topo-imagery/pull/767/files).