# How does `gdalinfo` round "STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT"?

Tags: gdal, gdalinfo

Basically, would 1 valid pixel in a 1,000x1,000 pixel image be rounded to 0 or 1? Would 999,999 valid pixels in a 1,000x1,000 pixel image be rounded to 99 or 100?

Based on the [tests](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AOSGeo%2Fgdal%20STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT&type=code), it looks like none of them verify this behaviour.

(Sorry for the shouting, but "STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT" is the literal key in the output.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code is here https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/698/files#diff-0586efbfe00d97a43de0a0b19f6618de6177578be50c74a4c6cc396f364db441R4786.

Interesting part includes comments:

```
        /* percentage is only an indicator: limit precision */
        CPLsnprintf( szValue, sizeof(szValue), "%.4g",
                 100. * static_cast<double>(nValidCount) / nSampleCount );

        if (EQUAL(szValue, "100"))
        {
            /* don't set 100 percent valid 
             * because some of the sampled pixels were nodata */
            SetMetadataItem( "STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT", "99.999" );
        }
        else
        {
            SetMetadataItem( "STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT", szValue );
        }
```

It seems that with only one valid pixel the validity percentage is rounded into 0, but with only one invalid pixel the validity is presented as 99.999.

Comment: Thank you! Damn, that means I can't use 0 as "no pixels at all", so even with that value there could still be some useful data in the image.

Comment: I think that you must have a closer look to the histogram but I do not know how to utilize the output from `gdalinfo -hist...` in some effective way in scripts. Maybe the ´-json` option in gdalinfo of the most new GDAL versions could be useful for that purpose.